# Recent activity Webpart sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I need to create recent activity webpart in sharepoint 2010,

The webpart should show the activities of last few days of of a  specific library.

Do you have any idea on how you would approach that?

Comment: I check out the RSS feeds and the Mysite options just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to turn on the audit logging and then trawl through the logs for the activity against the location. There you will see all check-in, out, open and upload, edit, etc.